# Is url.com?somephpcode vulnerable to anything from my code?

Tags: php

I never knew how to use the php code after the web url "?", and I don't even know what's the name of that...However, when the user failed to log in, I did something like this

```
//Failed login
header('Location: login?error_login');
```

and then the login page is:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/login?error_login"{
echo "you have submitted invalid login information";
}
```

The reason why I did it is that I have login form in the index so the user can log in from index page and don't have to go to login page, and well it works, but is this somekind vulnerable to anything in my php? Or better question so I don't get too many downvotes: What is the better way to perform something like this? Thanks.

*I'm not using .php in urls as I removed it from .htaccess... writing it just in case you would try to correct my "login?error_login" to "login.php?error_login"...*

Comment: The example you are giving is harmless. But you should keep in mind that anyone can read the parameter, and anyone can write it. Any information you provide about the workings of your code has a potential of being an attack vector. You should make sure you sanitize and plausibility-check everything you are getting via URL parameter, because it can never be trusted as-is.

Comment: This is exactly only one thing I actually did with url parameter, just to show up the error message, without the login?error_login it's just a normal login form without error messages, but it's kinda stupid that in this case, anybody can rewrite login to login?login_error and it'll pop out the error message...it's ridiculous though :/ How does facebook do it? I wanted to do it like facebook but when you are at login.php?login_attempts=x for the first time, it shows the error message, and when you refresh page it's just a normal login even though the login_attempt is there... how?

Comment: It is not true that "anyone can read the parameter and anyone can write it". If you use TLS (https), then people can't see it or change. If you **don't** use TLS, then anybody can see or change any part of your request, not just the url. The three reasons to avoid query strings are: 1) the information contains information you don't want the person behind you reading (eg. a password) 2) you wish to use semantics to make life easier for anyone else working on the system 3) you want prettier urls, though semanticly, anything referring to a specific resource should be in the url in some form.

Comment: But I think i'm misunderstood a bit... I'm not using it for query or mysqli, I'm just using it for my "key" to check for error message when user submit invalid login details... if he does, then he will be redirected to login page, and well I didn't want to just redirect it there without any error message on that page, so I added ?error_login to login page and then call the if to check if url is from failed login or just user went to login page straightly..

Comment: I don't understand where mysqli has come from, please see my answer below.

Comment: There is not really anything wrong with your attempt. But if you wanted to find out if the user _really_ came from an unsuccessful login, you could either use a session, or you could check the http_referrer (although that, too, can be faked). To clarify my previous comment: What you are doing here is OK. and anyone feelign the need to manipulate query strings will simply have to live with weird results. That, at least, is my opinion on that matter :-)

Comment: @Burki - I think you are the only one here that understands that I'm not doing it for mysqli or query but for **my** checking if user is from failed login or not. Your answer is the one I'm looking for though. Well I think that the session idea is one of the best, I tried it as first, and I tried some examples of unset, but unsuccessful and now I got an Idea, Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i am writing this as an answer for future readers)

The use of a query string in this specific example is not unsafe.
For many other examples, it might be, though.
The query string could be user input, and thus has to be treated as untrustworthy.

In your case, the worst that could happen is that a user messing with the query string would get weird resulst. This is their own problem, though, and need not concern you much (this is my opinion).

In any case where you would use the contents of the query string anywhere else in your code, say for a database query or any more interesting logic, you would at least have to sanitize it and verify it's plausibility.

On the other hand, you could also transport this information inside a session. That would allow for much more robustness, and it would not give away information about your code to a potential attacker.

Answer (score 1):

The part of the url after the `?` is the query string. It's useful for passing in additional information that is relevant to the requested resource. It can be accessed through the PHP global array `$_GET`

See the manual page here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

If you wish to send information without it being in the url, look at `$_POST`.

Here's it's manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Bare in mind that anything requesting a specific resource (eg, get information about album 6) should be in the url in some form. Something like error_login could be either, though it is easier to implement as part of the url.

Comment: But when I'm not passing anything from the url, is it still bad idea?

Comment: How do you mean? If you want to see if the query string contains `error_login`, you can do `array_key_exists('error_login', $_GET);`

Comment: it's not really about mysqli in this case, i just wanted any "key" to show the error message when user is redirected from index login form to login page,  when login failed.

Comment: I don't know where you got mysqli from. `$_GET` is an array which will contain a key for `error_login` if you sent it in the url query string, even if you did not set a value to it (eg `error_login=1`). You can use array_key_exists to check for its existence.

Comment: but i'm not using $_GET in my codes, just nowhere, please read my last comment on my question I described there some details I'm maybe misunderstood

Answer (score -1):

The string after `?` is a query string that can be get with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

> What is the better way to perform something like this?

There's no better way and it's just depends on a personal choice, for me I will try to implement it in the model–view–controller *(MVC)* way.

> But when I'm not passing anything from the url, is it still bad idea?

A client can pass any valid query string from the URL but there's still no bad idea by doing that, just make sure there's no vulnerability on your script that takes a query string such this:

```
...
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$unsafe_query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

// Vulnerable
$sql = "SELECT $unsafe_query";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

...
$conn->close();
```

One of the easiest way to get rid of this is to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`:

```
...
$unsafe_query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$safe_query = mysqli_real_escape_string($unsafe_query);

// Safe
$sql = "SELECT $safe_query";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm using prepared statements everywhere on the page tho

Comment: Even so, this is not the correct way to deal with this, you should use prepared statements. Or... better yet, an ORM

Comment: @DanielM Hey, I'm just giving the OP an example.. You're thinking a little mistake the scariest, are you sure you're a developer?

Comment: Perhaps I could have phrased it better, but am I wrong?